# Async Postback with Listview not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

I have a listview with a number of linkbuttons in. At the moment, when you click a button it triggers a full postback and I wanted to swap it so that it was only a partial postback. Seems like it ought to be simple enough, but I can't seem to get it to work, no matter what I do. Seems likely I'm missing something obvious, but at this point, I'm stumped.

Listview:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
  <section id="basketbox">
    <hgroup class="mainhead">
      <h2>Your basket</h2>
    </hgroup>
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" OnItemCommand="ListView1_ItemCommand" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="PartCode">
      <LayoutTemplate>
          <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></div>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
            <h4><%#Eval("Name") %></h4>
            <div class="quantitybox">
              <div class="qtylbl">Qty</div>
              <asp:LinkButton id="QtyDown" CommandArgument='<%#Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PartCode")%>' CssClass="qtybutton" CommandName="QtyDown" runat="server"><img src="/images/minus.png"></asp:LinkButton>
              <div class="qtybox"><%#Eval("Quantity") %></div>
              <asp:LinkButton id="QtyUp" CommandArgument='<%#Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PartCode")%>' CssClass="qtybutton" CommandName="QtyUp" runat="server"><img src="/images/plus.png"></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
  </section>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ListView1" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Things I've tried:
-ChildrenAsTriggers set to true (made no difference)

-Setting the triggers to be the linkbutton IDs (controls not found)

-Setting the page to be async in the page declaration (made no difference)

-Setting ClientIDMode to AutoID on the listview control (made no difference)

-Registering a linkbutton with the scriptmanager (code behind function below)

```
Private Sub RegisterPostBackControl()
    For Each item As ListviewItem In  ListView1.Items
        Dim lnkFull As LinkButton = TryCast(item.FindControl("QtyUp"), LinkButton)
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lnkFull)
    Next
End Sub
```

Again: no difference

I've also tried most of those in some combination with each other; none of which has made any difference at all.

What else should I try?

Comment: `Setting the page to be async in the page declaration (made no difference)` That's not related to UpdatePanel at all, that's for async/await support. `-Setting ClientIDMode to AutoID on the listview control (made no difference)` The ID on the client doesn't matter. Have you tried wrapping each LinkButton in it's own UpdatePanel? By the way, I recommend you abdandon UpdatePanel altogether ([because it's bad](http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/asp-net-web-forms-the-drunken-lovechild-of-desktop-and-web/)) and just use AJAX and [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: @mason I know UpdatePanels are the spawn of the devil - unfortunately, the project I'm working on has a deadline that's way too close for me to go away and master Web API for it. I haven't tried nesting update panels yet - I'll give that a go. (And thanks for the explanations - they were both things I tried on a "what the heck it might help" basis after tearing my hair out)

Comment: You don't *have* to use Web API, especially since it only works on .NET 4.5 (but it's ideal). I don't recommend ASMX either, since that service is basically deprecated. What I'd do if I were you is set up some generic handlers (.ashx). Have them fulfill the duties of a controller in Web API. You won't get the nice model binding stuff, and you'll manually need to pull values out of query string/form values. But it should all be straightforward and quick to implement. I know the temptation to just use UpdatePanel to "get it done", but you'll have to support this code presumably, right?

Comment: @Mason yes, I do have to support the code - which is the other reason why, at least at this point, I'd prefer not to have to learn an entirely new batch of coding just to support this one page on this one project! (Besides, when I say tight deadline I mean it's hopefully going live middle of next week.)

Comment: Nested Update Panels haven't helped (and just as a side issue, they also break my layout!)

Answer (score 0):

Your comments make it sound like you need to learn a lot to be able to use generic handler to respond to AJAX requests. That's not the case, you probably have the requisite knowledge

QtyDown.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class QtyChangeResponse
{
    public bool Success {get; set;}
    public string Message {get; set;}
}

public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        //pull values from query string
        //update database based on values
        //create response
        var responseObj = new QtyChangeResponse(){Success=true, Message="Qty Updated"};
        context.Response.ContentType="application/json";
        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseObj));       
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    { get { return false; } }
}
```

VB version(auto translated by Telerik)

```
Imports System.Web

Public Class QtyChangeResponse
    Public Property Success() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_Success
        End Get
        Set
            m_Success = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Success As Boolean
    Public Property Message() As String
        Get
            Return m_Message
        End Get
        Set
            m_Message = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Message As String
End Class

Public Class Handler
    Implements IHttpHandler
    Public Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)
        'pull values from query string
        'update database based on values
        'create response
        Dim responseObj = New QtyChangeResponse() With { _
            Key .Success = True, _
            Key .Message = "Qty Updated" _
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseObj))
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

So that's doing the same thing as a Web API controller would roughly.

```
<asp:LinkButton id="QtyDown" CssClass="qtybutton" runat="server" OnClientClick='QtyDown(<%#Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PartCode")%>); return false;'><img src="/images/minus.png"></asp:LinkButton>

<script type="text/javascript">
function QtyDown(partCode){
    //use your favorite JavaScript library to gather the quantity and PartCode and make a POST call to QtyDown.ashx?qty={quantity}&partcode={partcode)
}
</script>
```

Much easier to support, much less buggy than UpdatePanel, and I've done a lot of the work for you already.

Comment: 1) To be honest I probably DO have a lot to learn about this - my knowledge of .net is patchy and largely self-taught (thus the inevitable silly questions) 2) Unfortunately, I'm using vb.net so a c# solution REALLY doesn't help me

Comment: @FrustratedWDotNet C# and VB are so close that code converters exist that do a reasonable job. I've used one of those and updated my answer with the equivalent VB code. And no, if you can handle a postback from a Web Forms page and update the database, you can do the same from a generic handler. The only additional knowledge you need is JavaScript.